# Main Sidebar Dispappeared - What could possibly cause this?

Tags: sidebar

I used to have the drag & drop Widgets on Main Sidebar working but for some reason it no longer works. That is, whatever I place there (on the back-end) is no longer visible on the front-end.

In my attempts to troubleshoot this, I uninstalled completely the only 2 plugins I had:

1. "[Contact Form With Captcha](http://www.teknocrat.com/wordpress-contact-form-with-captcha-plugin.html)"
2. "[WP fade in text news](http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/04/22/wordpress-plugin-wp-fadein-text-news/Live%20Demo)"

But that didn't help.

I also switched back to the `twentyeleven` theme (from a child theme containing `style.css` only) but that didn't help either.

I also compared the content of the entire directory tree with pristine copy of the WordPress 3.3.1 ZIP package and found no differences. Does this point to some problem in some settings stored in the database?

Lastly, I tried the 3 different `Default Layout` settings in `Appearance > Theme Options`, just in case. That didn't help either.

What could possibly make the sidebar disappear?

Comment: did you edit functions.php? Try deactivating plugins. Try deleting and reinstalling twentyeleven or twentyten

Comment: @BandonRandon What plugins? I have no plugins installed. None whatsoever (see my original post). And no, I did not edit `functions.php`. It is **100%** identical to the original copy that came with `wordpress-3.3.1.tar.gz`.

Comment: @BandonRandon I also tried your tip: I uninstalled twentyeleven completely, then re-installed it. It didn't help. BTW, `twentyten` does show the sidebar. This appears to be a problem with `twentyelven` only (and its child).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much search I found an explanation to the mystery: With the new `Twenty Eleven` theme (from WordPress 3.2 and up), [the sidebar is gone](http://surminski.eu/2011/07/06/add-sidebar-to-single-post-in-the-wordpress-3-2-twentyeleven-theme/) in the **single post page**.